# Get dates from input type="month"

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following field:

```
<input type="month">
```

For the month/year selected  by a user in the field, I want to be able to get the date names and numbers for that month. Could anyone show me how to do this?

```
For example:
    May 2017 (31 days)
    1, Mon
    2, Tue
    3, Wed ...
```

I want to use the data obtained from the input to create table rows with dates.

Comment: you shouldn't do like this, you never know what client input to your input. how do you do if they input 5-2017, abc-2017 and alot of case happen here.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use `<input type="date">` or may use

```
<select name="month">
  <option value="jan">jan</option>
  <option value="feb">feb</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the intended use of that input type.  [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), an input with a type of "month" is:

> A control for entering a month and year, with no time zone.

So it gives you back a string like this: "2017-05".  You can do with that what you want from there.  The input isn't going to calculate the number of days in the month or associate day names for you.

If you want to get the value of the input, you can do something like this:

```
<input type="month" id="month">
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById('month');
  x.addEventListener('change', ()=> console.log(x.value))
</script>
```